# Xamarin Forms .NETStandard 1.4 resources issue

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've had converted my PCL project from classic Xamarin Forms to .NETStandard 1.4
and I have a issue with resources(*.resx)

> Error CS0103  The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current
>   context   Prog1Utilities  D:\MyProjects\Pro1\Pro1Utilities\WebUtilities\ApiService.cs 38  Active

How can I fix it?

Project.json

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.3.0",
    "Xam.Plugin.Connectivity": "2.2.12",
    "Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.3.168"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": "portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To make .resx work, you need to add Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility NuGet package. However, there are other problems with building after that. This is a well-known problem already and folks in Microsoft work on it. I'll update this post once I have any updates from them.

**Update (Dec '16)**

As of now, Xamarin is not fully compatible with .NET Standard according to Microsoft support. I'll be happy if someone prove me wrong.

**Update (Mar '17)**

The problem seems to be gone in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: What problems with building do you mean?

Comment: For example, `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility 1.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for mscorlib on Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win.`

Answer (score 0):

Using dnxcore50 in imports provide best possible api's support as per my experience so far. Try it.

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```